# Encoding repeated entries in pbtools

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf schema with a bunch of repeated structures.  Something like

```
syntax = "proto3";
package My

message TopLevel 
{
   string swVersion = 3;
   string reportMac = 4;
   string reportSsid = 6
}

message Temperature
{
   required uint64 ts = 1;
   required uint32 source = 3;
   repeated sint32 readings = 4;
}

message MyMessage
{
   required TopLevel topLevel = 1;
   repeated Temperature temperature = 2;
}
```

I compile with pbtools and get the structures and functions for Temperature and readings.  However I am having a hard time figuring out how to add "Temperature" entries dynamically.
Or am I out of luck and pbtools requires telling it ahead of time how many entries I have.  One problem is data is encoded as it is generated and I do not know how many of what I will have for each report.
I attached the generated code.

Comment: Never mind, can't attachfiles.  I'll post the relevant parts if it will help the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pbtools](https://github.com/eerimoq/pbtools) requires the length before adding any items.